# crosswalk: pull-to-refresh not working

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I'm building a simple hybrid app with cordova + crosswalk. Here is my config:

```
$ cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.6.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
```

According to my search, this would enable pull-to-refresh effect like Chrome by default. But I'm not seeing any effect. Here is my `config.xml` part that matters for crosswalk:

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="16+" />
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Crosswalk issue, please track https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6277